# What is this cookis in ASP.NET? IBM Pen test

Tags: cookies, asp.net-core

I am not able to figure out what cookie is this? The name of the cookie changes environment to environment and client browser.

I am using **ASP.NET RC5**. All cookies in image below are from my ASP.NET Site, just hidden the domain column in the image.

Could someone help me out please, IBM penetration test has picked up this :(

[image]

Comment: Look at the network tab and watch the response headers.  From there you should be able to see which endpoint served you the cookie, and that will give you a clue where it came from and for what purpose.

Comment: It is coming from my asp.net site (same domain).

Comment: Looks to me like something set by your application code, not the framework.